# Apply to each column and OR the result in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run `startsWith` from the `gdata` package on columns containing a bunch of strings. I would like to OR the result to get a list to use for indexing of rows containing a value that is starting with a certain value. So consider:

```
     A       B      C
1:  hello   jello  fello
2:  hello   hello  hello
3:  hello   hello  hello
4:  hello   hello  hello
5:  jello   hello  hello
6:  mello   hello  hello
```

And I want to find all rows that have an entry that starts with `jel` such the result is `T,F,F,F,T,F`. Is there a way to do this that doesn't require a `for`? The way I had considered is to cycle through the columns and `|` them together one by one. But I feel like there must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the function startwith, I think you should consider using the grep function, which can easily look up any pattern as the beginning of a string. So using your data table as an example:

```
DT <- data.table(A = c(rep("hello", 4), "jello", "mello"), B = c("jello", rep("hello", 5)), C = c("fello", rep("hello", 5)))
DT
```

#### output

```
       A     B     C
1: hello jello fello
2: hello hello hello
3: hello hello hello
4: hello hello hello
5: jello hello hello
6: mello hello hello
```

We can now use apply this way:

```
logicalList <- apply(DT, 1, function(x) { t <- grep("^jel",x); as.logical(sum(t))})
logicalList
```

#### output

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

The "1" in the apply function means we are applying the function that comes next on every row.
The "^" inside the grep means we only want strings that start with "jel" and this is your needed startwith part.
logicalList is a vector with the needed entries.

Comment: I would suggest using `any(grepl("^jel", x))` or `as.logical(length(grep("^jel", x)))` instead of you `sum` approach inside the anonymous function of apply.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `apply` and `any`:

```
apply(Dt, 1, function(x) any(startsWith(x, "jel")))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

---

```
Dt <- fread("
     A       B      C
hello   jello  fello
hello   hello  hello
hello   hello  hello
hello   hello  hello
jello   hello  hello
mello   hello  hello",
header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `grepl` and `rowSums` (this approach is vectorized and avoids calls to `apply` or `for` in R):

```
d <- read.table(textConnection("
     A       B      C
1:  hello   jello  fello
2:  hello   hello  hello
3:  hello   hello  hello
4:  hello   hello  hello
5:  jello   hello  hello
6:  mello   hello  hello"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

l <- grepl("^jel", as.matrix(d))
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# turn logical vector l into a matrix
l <- matrix(l, nrow=nrow(d), ncol=ncol(d))
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE

# more than one "jel" per row?
rowSums(l) > 0L
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**EDIT**: benchmark added.

The vectorized approach is the fastest (depending on the number of rows):

```
library("microbenchmark")
library("data.table")
library("gdata")

sgibb <- function(x, pat="^jel") {
  l <- matrix(grepl(pat, as.matrix(x)), nrow=nrow(x), ncol=ncol(x))
  rowSums(l) > 0L
}

nrussell <- function(x, pat="jel") {
  apply(x, 1, function(y) any(startsWith(y, pat)))
}

taljlevy <- function(x, pat="^jel") {
  apply(x, 1, function(y) { t <- grep(pat ,y); as.logical(sum(t))})
}

jeffkeller <- function(x, pat="^jel") {
  x[, index := apply(X = .SD, MARGIN = 1,
                      FUN = function(y)as.logical(sum(grep("^jel", y)))),
     .SDcols = c("A", "B", "C")]
  x
}

set.seed(123)
n <- 1e2
ch <- c("hello", "jello", "mello")
p <- c(0.95, 0.03, 0.02)
y <- data.table(A=sample(ch, n, replace=TRUE, prob=p),
                B=sample(ch, n, replace=TRUE, prob=p),
                C=sample(ch, n, replace=TRUE, prob=p))

microbenchmark(sgibb(y), nrussell(y), taljlevy(y), jeffkeller(y))
# Unit: microseconds
#           expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
#       sgibb(y)  260.111  286.826  329.3224  303.797  356.8475  524.321   100
#     nrussell(y) 1101.035 1159.175 1356.1322 1199.503 1448.1315 2566.077   100
#    taljlevy(y) 1223.317 1269.526 1401.5255 1295.018 1382.8875 2570.315   100
#  jeffkeller(y) 1778.812 1875.607 2088.9595 1929.091 2068.5515 3717.907   100

all.equal(sgibb(y), nrussell(y))
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(sgibb(y), jeffkeller(y)$index)
# [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option that combines several answers that have been suggested so far, but does it in more of a data.table-y way using **S**ubsets of **D**ata.table **col**umn**s** and without creating additional objects.

```
library(data.table)

Dt <- fread("
        A       B      C
        hello   jello  fello
        hello   hello  hello
        hello   hello  hello
        hello   hello  hello
        jello   hello  hello
        mello   hello  hello",
        header = TRUE)

Dt[, index := apply(X = .SD, MARGIN = 1,
                    FUN = function(x)as.logical(sum(grep("^jel",x)))),
   .SDcols = c("A", "B", "C")]

Dt # row index is available directly
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of

```
bar <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("hello", 
"jello", "mello"), class = "factor"), B = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("hello", "jello"), class = "factor"), 
    C = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("fello", 
    "hello"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:", "4:", "5:", "6:"))

(
foo <- subset(bar, grepl("j", A)  | grepl("j", B)  | grepl("jel", C))
)

#>       A     B     C
#>1: hello jello fello
#>5: jello hello hello
```